# UICollectionView scrollToItemAtIndex after button action executed

Tags: ios, swift

When the currentViewController is popped I want to scroll the `UICollectionView` in the `mainViewController` to the index of the item which the currentViewController was currently at. I've tried implementing this in `viewWillDisappear` of the currentViewController but nothing happens when the `back button` action is executed.

```
   override func viewWillDisappear(animated : Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        if (self.isMovingFromParentViewController()){
            let parent = parentViewController as! UINavigationController
            let child = parent.childViewControllers[0] as! MainViewController
            child.collectionView?.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forItem: currentIndex, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: .Top, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you are not **dismissing** but **popping** the viewcontroller something like this should work:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    if let mainViewController = navigationController?.topViewController as? MainViewController {
        mainViewController.collectionView?.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forItem: currentIndex, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: .CenteredVertically, animated: false)
    }
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
}
```

Comment: Just tried this, results remained the same unfortunately.

Comment: wanna share your project?

Comment: Yeah sure, i'll upload to github in a few minutes. I'll send the link in this chatroom http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106859/uicollectionview-scrolltoitematindex

Answer (score 0):

When your currentViewController is dismissed, then ViewWillAppear of mainViewController will be called. Here you can implement the scrollToItemAtIndexPath with condition check that viewwillappear was called from currentVC was dismissed not when mainVC was launch from other sources.

Comment: I tried implementing before asking the question. The `presentingViewController` returned nil each time it was called within `viewWillAppear`

Comment: What was returned nil? Also you can remove the code in viewwilldisappear

Comment: `presentingViewController`

Comment: Its a NavigationController app.. so from mainViewController it will be pushViewController to the currentVC and on back button it will be popVC...  can you add more code how you are pushing and dismissing the view.

Comment: The newVC is being pushed by a segue created within storyboard and `performSegueWithIdentifer`. Changes are made accordingly in `prepareSegue` (nothing special)

Answer (score 0):

Ended up created a protocol which was a lot more manageable that writtig everything in the `viewWillDisappear` of the childVC. Thank you [André Slotta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4051118/andr%C3%A9-slotta) for the suggestion.

```
protocol CurrentIndexDelegate{
    func setCurrentIndex(index: Int?)
}

class ChildViewController: UIViewController{
    var currentIndexDelegate : CurrentIndexDelegate? = nil
    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        if currentIndexDelegate != nil {
            currentIndexDelegate!.setCurrentIndex(currentIndex)
        }
    }
}

class MainViewController: UIViewController, CurrentIndexDelegate{
    var currentIndex: Int?
    func setCurrentIndex(index: Int?){
        currentIndex = index!
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        //Current index is set from delegate
        if(currentIndex != nil){
            collectionView?.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forItem: currentIndex!, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: .Top, animated: true)
        }
    }

}
```